# access scipy matrix in dense format

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, networkx

I was building graph using networks as follows:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>>
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 1.0)
>>> G.add_edge(1, 4, weight = 2.0)
>>> G.add_edge(2, 3, weight = 3.0)
>>> G.add_edge(2, 4, weight = 4.0)
>>> G.add_edge(3, 4, weight = 5.0)
>>> G.add_edge(3, 5, weight = 6.0)
>>> G.add_edge(4, 5, weight = 7.0)
```

then I compressed the matrix to scipy matrix using csr format:

```
S = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G, format='csr')
```

I recovered the matrix to its dense form:

```
>>> S.todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  7.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

How could I access each element of this matrix? I tried S.todense()[0][0]. But it doesn't work? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
S.todense()[0, 0]
```

`todense()` returns `np.matrix`, you also could use `.A` to return an`np.array`. In this case:

```
S.A[0][0]
```

Would work, but

```
S.A[0,0]
```

is still preferred.

Comment: @f4fc2791e4473eb2ba41b5ddb445b2, You could use `.A` if you want `np.array`.

Comment: How could I get the size of the matrix?

Comment: `S.shape` will give you `(n_rows, n_cols)`, `S.size` will give you number of non-zero elements.